# Change color of glyphicon

Tags: html, colors

I used this html code to show a color of a project:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" data-ng-style="{'color': projectUserConnection.project.color}"></span>
```

now I will provide to change the color in that way that if `glyphicon` is clicked a color chooser should be opened. Does anyone know how to include or something else

```
<input type="color">
```

into the span or how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: [JSCOLOR](http://jscolor.com/)

> CODE

You can find all information on their site by the way for make the answer complete i add there the example code from the site that i think you will need to use.

```
<script src="jscolor.js"></script>

<p>You can add the color picker to a BUTTON:
<button class="jscolor {value:'66ccff'}"></button>

<p>... which might be empty to just display the color:
<button
    class="jscolor {valueElement:null,value:'66ccff'}"
    style="width:50px; height:20px;"></button>

<p>... and can be styled too:
<button
    class="jscolor {valueElement:null,value:'66ccff'}"
    style="border:2px solid black">
    Pick a color
</button>
```

Please tell me if this is something that can help you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color:blue"></span>
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user blue"></span>
```

**CSS**

```
.blue {
    color: blue;
}
```